# Get all Usernames by IP row from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So, everytime when someone registers on my server, their IP get's saved on ROW named "IP".

I want to get, every "USERNAME" row,  by the same "IP" row saved.

Eg:  Accounts:  Mike,  John  are saved on IP 127.0.0.1

I want to select IP 127.0.0.1  and show me Mike, John.

Currently I did this:

```
$sql10 = "SELECT IP, username, pHour FROM users  order by pHour DESC LIMIT 5;";
$results10 =  array();
$result10 = mysqli_query($con,$sql10);

$results10 = mysqli_fetch_all($result10, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$output10 = '';

foreach ($results10 as $row) {
    $output10 .= ' ' . $row['username'] . ' and ' . $row['pHour'] . '
';
}
```

I think that, I should add

```
SELECT username, IP, pHour FROM users WHERE IP = '$row['IP']' order by pHour
```

I'm on a good way to do it or not even close?

Simply, I want to get every username and pHour from the row 'IP'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: @Cid  it's not duplicate, I know how to get client IP address, I just don't know how to get "Username" rows based on his IP adress.

Comment: Is the IP saved in DB?

Comment: update your question and add  the table schema a data sample and the expetced  result and the db you are using  too

Comment: @Cid  yes in row named IP.

Comment: @scaisEdge  updated.

Comment: GROUP BY IP ?...

Comment: which db you are using .. and which data type is usedc for column ip?

Comment: @scaisEdge I want to echo it inside the HTML, I'm using MySQL db, it's used varchar.

Comment: Did you at least tried to execute the query you've shown?*

Comment: `WHERE IP = '$row['IP']'` - You would first need to have another query before that. You should be getting errors here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner then how should I proceed?

Comment: You probably might have to join the usernames using something equivalent like `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` in sqlserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add  where condition for filter  the rows  ip

assuming your ip column is  saved in a string column named  ip

```
$sql10 = "SELECT username, pHour 
            FROM users 
            where ip = '127.0.0.1'
            order by pHour DESC LIMIT 5;";
```

you could use for passing the ip as a var

```
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT username, pHour 
        FROM users
        where ip = ?');
    $sth->bind_param("s",  $your_ip_var);

    $sth->execute();
```

Comment: Instead of  where ip = '127.0.0.1'     can I add  where ip = '$row['IP']'  ?  which gets the current session's IP row from mysql

Comment: *"assuming you are PDO"* - They're using the mysqli_ api here; look at their code ;-)

Comment: Noticing the edit: `where ip = :my_ip'` and `bind_param()` are of 2 different apis.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner  ..thanks for the suggestion  ... answer   updated

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was looking for.